# Can I access pointers the same way as arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I have `int *integers;` and I allocate memory using
`integers = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);`, can I access, say the 2nd value stored in there with `integers[1]`, or do I have to do that with `*(integers + 1)`?

Comment: Yes. You can. That is the normal way.

Comment: Thanks, so is it basically a "dynamic array" when using it that way?

Comment: @Algorithmiker - be wary of the term "dynamic". It has several meanings. Be sure you don't apply the incorrect one here.

Comment: Ther is harld anything useful you can do with **arrays** actually, except take their address, size and alignment. The index-operator for example is applied to a pointer only, not an array. What about pointers in your C book **specifically** is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscript operator `[]` is *defined* in terms of pointer arithmetic. The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)` - given the address `a`, offset `i` elements from that address and dereference the result<sup>1</sup>.

So, yes, you can use the `[]` operator on a pointer expression as well as an array expression.

Remember that with pointer arithmetic, the size of the pointed-to type is taken into account - if `a` is a pointer to an `int`, then `a + 1` yields the address of the *next integer object* (which can be anywhere from 2 to 4 to 8 bytes from `a`).

Also remember that *arrays are not pointers* - an array expression will be *converted* ("decay") to a pointer expression unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

---

1. This also means that array indexing is commutative - `a[1] == 1[a]`.  However, you'll rarely see `i[a]` outside of the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access values through pointers as if they were arrays.

In normal circumstances (any use except after `&`, `sizeof`, or a string literal) an array gets converted to a pointer to its first element, so, in effect, using an array is converted to using a pointer, not the other way round.

Comment: You cannot index an array! The array name is converted ot a pointer before the index-operator is applied.

Answer (score 0):

> can I access, say the 2nd value stored in there with integers[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), or do I have to do that with *(integers + 1)?

Yes, you can. Array names decay to pointers so in both cases, you can act as if you have a pointer pointing at the first element of your data.

**NOTE** : See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) on why you should not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: "Array names decay to pointers" - is wrong. They decay **for most usages**. But not always as the statement implies. And it is not "as-if", but they  _are_ converted to pointers to the first element.